# how to display japanese caracters in angular on utf 8 to japanese

Tags: angularjs, unicode

I'm trying to use the unicode system to render the proper japanese value char:

```
'&#x30A1'  =  &#x30A1;
```

So, when I make the `$scope.name = '&#x30A1';` the japanese char `&#x30A1;` is not rendering.

What should I do maybe a regex? Something like this:

```
#Match Katakana

regex = u'[\u30A0-\u30FF]+' # == u'[ァ-ヾ]+'
```

Comment: Why not `$scope.name = 'ァ'`?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I actually solve the problem using 'ngsanitize'
here is the sample

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.myHTML = 'I am an   &#12470  string with '

      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example61-production</title>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation `&#x30A1;` is an HTML and XML character reference. In JavaScript, it is just a string of eight Ascii characters, with no special meaning.

Instead, use the character itself, as @zeroflagL suggests in a comment: `$scope.name = 'ァ'`, provided that the file is actually UTF-8 encoded and this encoding is properly declared. If this is not feasible, use the *JavaScript* notation for referring to a character by its Unicode number: `$scope.name = '\u30A1'`. This works independently of character encoding.